# ¿Cómo esperar que un valor de una BD cambie antes de continuar?

Tags: firebase, flutter

Tengo ciertos productos y necesito que no puedan ser comprados por varios usuarios a la vez ya que podrían comprar más de la cantidad disponible. Para esto cada vez que un usuario inicia el proceso de comprar un producto cambio una propiedad de mi base de datos (`isBeingBought/idDelProducto`) a true. Entonces, si un usuario inicia una compra, quiero que la aplicación confirme que nadie más esta comprando el producto (`isBeingBought/idDelProducto == false`) y si alguien lo está haciendo (`isBeingBought/idDelProducto == true`), que al aplicación espere hasta que la propiedad vuelva a ser `false`.

Para esto hice la función `awaitNobodyIsBuying` que es un `Future` que espera hasta que al propiedad sea `true`

```
 static Future<void> awaitNobodyIsBuying(String id, String weight) async {
        DatabaseReference ref = await FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref()
.child("isBeingBought/$id");
        final body = await ref.get();
        if(body.value!=null && body.value as bool){
          await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1)).then((event) {
              awaitNobodyIsBuying(id, weight);
          });
        }
    }
```

Esta función lo que hace es preguntar si la propiedad es `true` y si lo es esperar un segundo y volver a preguntar.

La llamo cuando se presiona el botón de comprar:

```
onPressed:() async {
await ProductDatabaseService.awaitNobodyIsBuying(buyProducProvider.productSelected!.id, buyProducProvider.caliberSelected!.weight);

//Realizar compra....
}
```

el problema es que el método funciona correctamente, al revisarlo con el Debugger se mantiene en bucle hasta que cambio manualmente la propiedad a `false`. Sin embargo, la aplicación no espera y mientras aun se ejecuta el método `awaitNobodyIsBuying` se siguen ejecutando los demás métodos.

Utilizo la base de datos realtime de firebase.

¿Cómo puedo solucionarlo? ¿Acaso hay algún método más eficiente con algún listener o algo así?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al momento de usar el `await` detiene el flujo hasta obtener respuesta, pero al usar `then`, lo que haces es recibir la respuesta asíncronamente mientras el flujo sigue, tendrías que esperar y retornar, así:

```dart
 static Future<void> awaitNobodyIsBuying(String id, String weight) async {
        DatabaseReference ref = await FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref()
.child("isBeingBought/$id");
        final body = await ref.get();
        if(body.value!=null && body.value as bool){
          await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));
          return awaitNobodyIsBuying(id, weight);
        }
    }
```